# Usage of the words 'too' and 'also'

Tags: word-choice, adverbs, word-order, too-also

What are the rules regarding the use of *too* and *also*? I have read some relevant answers, but none made it clear.

If someone says "my phone is working", what should I reply?

1. Mine is working too
2. Mine is working also

Comment: Could you give sentences in which you would use the one and the other, and then we can explain if you are not using them properly.

Comment: Check out http://www.englishpage.com/minitutorials/also.html

Comment: if someone says- my phone is working. what should i say mine is working too or mine is working also?

Comment: You'd say *my phone is working too* or *my phone is also working*. To say *my phone is working also* sounds unnatural.

Answer (score 2):

> If someone says- “My phone is working.” What should I reply? *Mine is working too* (or) *Mine is working also*

Either of those are correct and natural-sounding. "As well" would work as well. :-)

I prefer "too" but that's just me.

Comment: It is not natural to say *my phone is working also*. That sounds foreign. You'd naturally say *my phone is also working*.

Comment: I don't have a problem with *my phone is working also* (it doesn't sound unnatural to me), but I agree *my phone is also working* sounds better-stated.

Answer (score 1):

Both "too" and "also" can be used as adverbs at the end of a clause like that and have the same meaning.

"Also" can also be used as a normal adverb. Like in the first sentence of this paragraph: You can say, "The word can also be used ...", but you CAN'T say "The word can too be used ..."

Finally, "also" can be used as a conjunction. "We need to clean the house. Also, we want to mow the lawn." Use of "too" as a conjunction is archaic.

Answer (score 1):

Mine is working too or mine is working also?

Grammatically and semantically, both sentences are correct.  The only difference between them is as follows:

1- It's common and natural to use "too" at the end of a sentence, whereas also is not much used so and and is not considered natural if used at the end of the sentence. Also is normally used before a verb, after an auxiliary verb and sometimes at the beginning of a sentence.

2- The use of "also" is a bit formal. On the other hand, the use of "too" is much more natural and common in spoken and informal English.